# no such table: main.auth_user__old (OperationalError)

Tags: python, sql, django

Environment:

Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/main/tutorial/add/

Django Version: 2.1.4
Python Version: 3.8.2

Traceback:

```
File "/home/webdev/Desktop/my_django_app/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in _execute
  85.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "/home/webdev/Desktop/my_django_app/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py" in execute
  296.         return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)

The above exception (no such table: main.auth_user__old) was the direct cause of the following exception:

File "/home/webdev/Desktop/my_django_app/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "/home/webdev/Desktop/my_django_app/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  126.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/home/webdev/Desktop/my_django_app/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  124.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/home/webdev/Desktop/my_django_app/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in wrapper
  604.                 return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)

File "/home/webdev/Desktop/my_django_app/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  142.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/webdev/Desktop/my_django_app/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  44.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/webdev/Desktop/my_django_app/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py" in inner
  223.             return view(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/webdev/Desktop/my_django_app/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in add_view
  1637.         return self.changeform_view(request, None, form_url, extra_context)

File "/home/webdev/Desktop/my_django_app/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapper
  45.         return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)

File "/home/webdev/Desktop/my_django_app/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  142.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/webdev/Desktop/my_django_app/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in changeform_view
  1525.             return self._changeform_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context)

File "/home/webdev/Desktop/my_django_app/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in _changeform_view
  1568.                     self.log_addition(request, new_object, change_message)

File "/home/webdev/Desktop/my_django_app/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in log_addition
  804.         return LogEntry.objects.log_action(

File "/home/webdev/Desktop/my_django_app/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/models.py" in log_action
  29.         return self.model.objects.create(

File "/home/webdev/Desktop/my_django_app/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py" in manager_method
  82.                 return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)

File "/home/webdev/Desktop/my_django_app/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in create
  413.         obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)

File "/home/webdev/Desktop/my_django_app/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in save
  717.         self.save_base(using=using, force_insert=force_insert,

File "/home/webdev/Desktop/my_django_app/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in save_base
  748.             updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)

File "/home/webdev/Desktop/my_django_app/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in _save_table
  831.             result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)

File "/home/webdev/Desktop/my_django_app/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in _do_insert
  868.         return manager._insert([self], fields=fields, return_id=update_pk,

File "/home/webdev/Desktop/my_django_app/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py" in manager_method
  82.                 return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)

File "/home/webdev/Desktop/my_django_app/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in _insert
  1136.         return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)

File "/home/webdev/Desktop/my_django_app/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in execute_sql
  1289.                 cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "/home/webdev/Desktop/my_django_app/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  100.             return super().execute(sql, params)

File "/home/webdev/Desktop/my_django_app/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  68.         return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)

File "/home/webdev/Desktop/my_django_app/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in _execute_with_wrappers
  77.         return executor(sql, params, many, context)

File "/home/webdev/Desktop/my_django_app/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in _execute
  85.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "/home/webdev/Desktop/my_django_app/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/utils.py" in __exit__
  89.                 raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value

File "/home/webdev/Desktop/my_django_app/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in _execute
  85.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "/home/webdev/Desktop/my_django_app/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py" in execute
  296.         return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)

Exception Type: OperationalError at /admin/main/tutorial/add/
Exception Value: no such table: main.auth_user__old
```

Comment: Did you properly make migrations and migrate the database?

Answer (score 0):

try this commands:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

and then rerun your server.

Comment: i made migrations..when i fill all content title and date and click save..at this point of saving im getting error

Comment: @Mubin_Hardy try removing migration folders first (ofc if its not production server)